# Different behaviour of dataclass default_factory to generate list

Tags: typeerror, field, python-dataclasses

I'm quite new to Python so please have me excused if this question contain some newbie misunderstandings, but I've failed to google the answer for this:

On my personal laptop running Python 3.9.7 on Windows 11 this code is working without errors.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field


@dataclass
class SomeDataClass:
    somelist: list[str] = field(default_factory=lambda:['foo', 'bar'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    instance = SomeDataClass()
    print(instance)
```

But when at work running Python 3.8.5 on Windows 10 I get the following error:

`File "c:\...\test_dataclass.py", line 13, in SomeDataClass`
`somelist: list[str] = field(default_factory=lambda:['foo', 'bar'])`

`TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable`

I'd like to understand why this behaves differently and what I could do to make it work.

I would expect dataclasses to behave similarly on both computers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already intuited the reason: this is a new feature in version 3.9.  You can see it in the *What's New* article for 3.9 [here](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.9.html#type-hinting-generics-in-standard-collections).

This feature is available in version 3.8 as well, but it is not enabled by default.  You can enable it in your code by including this import:

```
from __future__ import annotations
```

Comment: Thank you - I would have had a hard time understanding that was the solution. I can't even understand that my problem and your solution is related reading the contents of the link you gave, so how this actually works will have to grow on me as I'm getting confused at a higher level. At least I know how to proceed.

Comment: Basically, the `list[str]` syntax doesn't mean anything in older versions of Python. Because the designers knew that it would mean something in the future, they gave users the option of enabling the feature so they could write future-proof code, even though that code wouldn't do anything yet. You can read some more here: https://peps.python.org/pep-0585/#implementation